# How to synchronize file systems to Azure Blob storage without using AZCopy?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, onpremises-gateway

I would like to sync or send files from the file system (via On-premises Data Gateway) to Azure Blobs.
But, I need a solution different than using AZCopy.

Is it possible to define a kind of Azure File Share which sync with Azure Blob Storage automatically?

Comment: Just curious - why you don't want to use AZCopy?

Comment: Have you heard about azure data factory? Basically it’s a tool to move data from point A to point B

Answer (score 0):

Create an Azure Data Factory pipeline to transfer files between an on-premises machine and Azure Blob Storage

**1)** To add a source linked service, open the '**Connections**' tab on the '**Factory Resources**' panel, add new connection and select the '**File System'** type from the ADF authoring screen.

[image]

**2)** Assign the name to the linked service name, select 'OnPremIR' from the integration runtime drop-down list, enter your domain user name in the format of 'USERNAME@DOMAINNAME', as well as a password. Finally, hit the 'Test connection' button to ensure ADF can connect to your local folder

[image]

**3)** To add a destination linked service, add a new connection and select Azure Blob Storage type
[image]

**4)** Assign the name for the linked service, select '**Use account key**' as the authentication method, select Azure subscription and storage account name from the respective drop-down lists.

[image]

**5)** Now that we have linked services in place, we can add the source and destination datasets, here are the required steps.

- To add source dataset, press **'+'** on '**Factory Resources**' panel and select 'Dataset'.
- Open '**File**' tab, select '**File System**' type and confirm.

[image]

**6)** Assign the name to newly created dataset (I named it 'LocalFS_DS') and switch to the '**Connection**' tab.

[image]

**7)** Finally, open the '**Schema**' tab and hit the '**Import Schema**' button to import files

[image]

- Similar to the source dataset, hit '+' on 'Factory Resources' panel
  and select 'Dataset', to add the destination dataset.
- Select the 'Azure Blob Storage' type and confirm.
- Enter dataset name (I named it 'BlobSTG_DS') and open 'Connection'
  tab
- Select blob storage

[image]

**8)** The last step in this process is -adding pipeline and activity.

- Press '+' on 'Factory Resources' panel and select 'Pipeline'.
- Assign the name to the pipeline (I named it as 'OnPremToBlob_PL').
- Expand 'Move & Transform' category on the 'Activities' panel and drag
  & drop 'Copy Data' activity onto central panel.
- Select newly added activity and assign the name (I named it
  'FactInternetSales_FS_BS_AC').
- Switch to 'Source' tab and select LocalFS_DS dataset we created
  earlier.

[image]

- Switch to 'Sink' tab and select 'BlobSTG_DS' dataset we created
  earlier.
  [image]

**9)**  Publishing these changes-hit 'Publish All' and check notifications area for deployment status.  using the '**Trigger Now**' command under the '**Trigger' menu**
[image].

To check the execution results, open ADF Monitoring page and ensure that pipeline's execution was successful.

[image]

To verify that files have been transferred successfully, switch to the your  blob storage screen and open the your  container.

For more details refer this [document](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5928/transfer-onpremises-files-to-azure-blob-storage/)