# What is the best method to sync medical images between my client PCs and my Azure Blob storage through a cloud-based web application?

Tags: file-upload, azure-blob-storage, syn

What is the best method to sync medical images between my client PCs and my Azure Blob storage through a cloud-based web application? I tried to use MS Azure Blob SDK v18, but it is not that fast. I'm looking for something like dropbox, fast, resumable and efficient parallel uploading.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

**AzCopy** is a command-line tool for copying data to or from Azure Blob storage, Azure Files, and Azure Table storage, by using simple commands. The commands are designed for optimal performance. Using **AzCopy**, you can either copy data between a file system and a storage account, or between storage accounts. **AzCopy** may be used to copy data from local (on-premises) data to a storage account.

And also  You can create a scheduled task or cron job that runs an AzCopy command script. The script identifies and uploads new on-premises data to cloud storage at a specific time interval.

Fore more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-migrate-on-premises-data?tabs=windows)

**Solution 2:**

Azure Data Factory is a fully managed, cloud-based, data-integration ETL service that automates the movement and transformation of data.

By using Azure Data Factory, you can create data-driven workflows to move data between on-premises and cloud data stores. And you can process and transform data with Data Flows. ADF also supports external compute engines for hand-coded transformations by using compute services such as Azure HDInsight, Azure Databricks, and the SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) integration runtime.

Create an Azure Data Factory pipeline to transfer files between an on-premises machine and Azure Blob Storage.

For more details refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819833/how-to-synchronize-file-systems-to-azure-blob-storage-without-using-azcopy/68843896#68843896)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But I need to have azcopy installed on all my clients' PCs?
@ShrutiJoshi-MT

Comment: Ya, You need to install AzCopy in client systems.